# Is it possible to ingest data into Kusto based on a multirow result set?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to ingest data from the `Food` table into a table `CurrentFood` based on filter criteria (finding the latest date per type). The query to get input data is something like this:

```
Food
| summarize arg_max(Date, Date) by Type
```

| Type | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Fruit | 06-02-2022 |
| Vegetables | 01-01-2022 |
| ... | ... |

Based on the rows returned I want to ingest into `CurrentFood`. Every row returned needs to be used as a filter where `Type` and `Date` match. Essentially, one ingestion per row but I'd like to have it all as one single ingestion.

```
// Ingest 1st row data
.set-or-replace CurrentFood <| Food
| where Type == "Fruit" and Date == "06-02-2022"

// Ingest 2nd row data
.set-or-append CurrentFood <| Food
| where Type == "Vegetable" and Date == "01-01-2022"

// Ingest 3rd row data
.set-or-append CurrentFood <| Food
...
```

Pseudo-code below for what I'd like to achieve:

```
.set-or-replace CurrentFood <| Food
| where
  {for each row in result set find those entries where Type and Date match}
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but if would have to guess the reason for the downvote - when you're asking a data question, you are expected to give a decent data sample, the required results (a dataset) and a short description of the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo**

```
.set-or-replace Food <|
datatable (RecordID:int, Name:string, Type:string, Date:datetime)
[
     1 ,"Grapes"   ,"Fruit"      ,"2022-02-04"
    ,2 ,"Orange"   ,"Fruit"      ,"2022-02-06"
    ,3 ,"Grapes"   ,"Fruit"      ,"2022-02-06"
    ,4 ,"Apple"    ,"Fruit"      ,"2022-02-06"
    ,5 ,"Orange"   ,"Fruit"      ,"2022-02-05"
    ,6 ,"Mango"    ,"Fruit"      ,"2022-02-05" 
    ,7 ,"cucumber" ,"Vegetables" ,"2022-01-01"
    ,8 ,"Broccoli" ,"Vegetables" ,"2022-01-01"
]
```

---

Based on [partition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/partitionoperator) & [row_rank()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/rowrankfunction)

```
.set-or-replace CurrentFood <|
Food
|   partition hint.strategy=native by Type
    (
        order by Date 
        |   where row_rank(Date) == 1
    )
```

---

```
CurrentFood
```

| RecordID | Name | Type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | cucumber | Vegetables | 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z |
| 8 | Broccoli | Vegetables | 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z |
| 2 | Orange | Fruit | 2022-02-06T00:00:00Z |
| 3 | Grapes | Fruit | 2022-02-06T00:00:00Z |
| 4 | Apple | Fruit | 2022-02-06T00:00:00Z |

Or

Based on [summarize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/summarizeoperator) & [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer)

```
.set-or-replace CurrentFood <|
let MaxDates = Food | summarize Date = max(Date) by Type;
MaxDates
| join kind=inner Food on Type, Date
| project-away *1
```

---

```
CurrentFood
```

| Type | Date | RecordID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vegetables | 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z | 7 | cucumber |
| Vegetables | 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z | 8 | Broccoli |
| Fruit | 2022-02-06T00:00:00Z | 2 | Orange |
| Fruit | 2022-02-06T00:00:00Z | 3 | Grapes |
| Fruit | 2022-02-06T00:00:00Z | 4 | Apple |

Comment: With the join version I'm getting: `'join' operator has exceeded the memory budget`. The list of `MaxDates` is about 400 elements, but `Food` is millions of rows. Is it executing `MaxDates` for every row?

Comment: Not sure what you are doing there. I just ran a demo on 10M records, on an ADX free cluster, were the Names and Types where GUID converted to string. Please share some statistics on your data distribution (range of dates, number of elements per type etc,) as well as a sample row.

Comment: (1) Please note that the small table (MaxDates) is on the left side of the join. See "join operator" in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/best-practices. (2) In addition to (1), `hint.strategy=broadcast` (for the join) might improve performance significantly if Food is a large table

Comment: Using the smaller dataset first was key. Thank you for your input! Highly appreciated!